If parent spans all grid columns is it possible for child elements to work to grid?
I've got a simple grid. Some elements (for example the <footer>) span all the columns. Is it possible to get child elements inside the footer to work to the same underlying grid? Without setting up exactly the same grid on the parent element?


main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

footer {
  grid-column: 1 / -1; /* this gets the footer to span all columns */
}

footer { /* can this be avoided? */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
<main>
  <footer>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some more text</p>
  </footer>
</main>




https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Subgrid

Why do you have footer twice in you CSS and why do you have -1;?
Please clarify what you mean/want as the end result here by "child items to work to grid"

Hey thank you, didn't know subgrid existed. Do you want to 'answer' this post?

Don't edit your question with an answer. Create a separate actual answer, it's allowed

subgrid is the answer here.

If [on the nested grid] you set the value subgrid on grid-template-columns, grid-template-rows or both, instead of creating a new track listing the nested grid uses the tracks defined on the parent.



main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

footer {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  /* this gets the footer to span all columns */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
}

p {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
<main>
  <footer>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some more text</p>
  </footer>
</main>



